# I am stack with errors using this command pip install nvidia-tensorflow[horovod]

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, nvidia

````
(tensorholo) C:\Users\alaba\Desktop\MIT PROJECT\tensor_holography-main>pip install nvidia-tensorflow[horovod]
Collecting nvidia-tensorflow[horovod]
  Downloading nvidia-tensorflow-0.0.1.dev5.tar.gz`` (7.9 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error


  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\alaba\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ztjzt002\nvidia-tensorflow_001bf7a090024c37a3c7ff91374ac7c4\setup.py", line 150, in <module>
          raise RuntimeError(open("ERROR.txt", "r").read())
      RuntimeError:
      ###########################################################################################
      The package you are trying to install is only a placeholder project on PyPI.org repository.
      This package is hosted on NVIDIA Python Package Index.

      This package can be installed as:
      ```
      $ pip install nvidia-pyindex
      $ pip install nvidia-tensorflow
      ```

      Please refer to NVIDIA instructions: https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorflow#install.
      ###########################################################################################
````

This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

```
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Answer (score 3):

`nvidia-tensorflow[horovod]` package doesn't support the Windows platform. You'd need to run it inside a WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux version 2) to make it work on Windows.

Like [the official docs say](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorflow#install):

> The `nvidia-tensorflow` package includes CPU and GPU support for Linux.

And also [this issue](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorflow/issues/58) on the same repository: